# How to build a Multi-Theme website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to build a multi-theme website, I know a method which is to make multiple CSS files with the same variable names and the colors I want, then add **link** element to my HTML file with an id of theme and then select it using javascript and change its **href** to whatever CSS file (Theme) I want.

Are there any better ways?

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: if you want multi-theme, use css vars :) `--primary-clr: red;` `--secondary-clr: green;` and in javascript changing one property with `element.style.setProperty("--primary-clr", "yellow")`. if you want really simplier solution. make that data inside a js object `{}` and a function that have as a parameter that json object. if you want just dark/light theme changes just use `color-scheme: light dark;`. if you want a answer I will write to you something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply different classes to the body element depending on the selected theme and then build the css to reference that. For example

```
body.theme_1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

body.theme_1 .header {
    font-color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}

body.theme_2 {
    background-color: pink;
}

body.theme_2 .header {
    font-colour: yellow;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS custom properties (variables) and JavaScript to toggle between themes by clicking on a button. You can have as many themes as you want. In the example below, I switch between dark and light by toggling a `dark` class:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", ()=> document.documentElement.classList.toggle("dark"))
```

```css
:root {
  --forground: black;
  --background: white;
}

.dark {
  --forground: white;
  --background: black;
}

* {
  color: inherit;
}

html {
  background-color: var(--background);
  color: var(--forground);
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<button>Change the theme</button>
<h1>Hello, I'm a dummy heading</h1>
```

For dark and light, you can also use [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) from CSS without any JavaScript. And the theme is set according to the user's machine preference:

```css
:root {
  --forground: black;
  --background: white;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --forground: white;
    --background: black;
  }
}

* {
  color: inherit;
}

html {
  background-color: var(--background);
  color: var(--forground);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, I'm a dummy heading</h1>
```